# Verilog: Concatenation of defines gives compilation error

Tags: concatenation, verilog

I have a strange error in Verilog RTL compilation. I have 2 defines and a concatenation of them gives error.

```
`define ARRAY1 = 3'b001;
`define ARRAY2 = 3'b011;

[...]

next_state = {`ARRAY1,`ARRAY2};
```

```
xmvlog: *E,ILLPRI (./../rtl/LVDS_ctrl_phy.v,271|37): illegal expression primary [4.2(IEEE)].
(`define macro: ARRAY1 [./../rtl/LVDS_ctrl_phy.v line 1], file: ./../rtl/LVDS_ctrl_phy.v line 271)
                 next_state = {`ARRAY1,`ARRAY2};
```

Since `define` is merely a text substitution, this shouldn't give error, right?
But, if I substitute with the corresponding text

```
next_state = {3'b001,3'b011};
```

this does not give an error.

Do you have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 3):

A tick-define is like a text-editor search and replace. These tick-defines

```
`define ARRAY1 = 3'b001;
`define ARRAY2 = 3'b011;
```

effectively mean

```
replace all occurrences of `ARRAY1 with "= 3'b001;"
replace all occurrences of `ARRAY2 with "= 3'b021;"
```

so

```
next_state = {`ARRAY1,`ARRAY2};
```

becomes

```
next_state = {= 3'b001;,= 3'b021;};
```

which is nonsense. Basically, remove the semicolons and equals from these lines:

```
`define ARRAY1 3'b001
`define ARRAY2 3'b011
```

Comment: Or use `parameter ARRAY1 = 3'b001; parameter ARRAY2 = 3'b011; ` instead